# Replace a character in one string with a character from another string in C++

Tags: c++

I am making a cypher program for my C++ project. My approach is to declare and initialise two strings, the first one being `alphabet` and the other being `key`, as shown below.

```
string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
string key {"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"};
```

I want to pair all these 52 letters to one another in the cypher. That is, small `a` is replaced with capital `Z`, small `b` with `Y` and so on.

The user will be prompted to enter a string, which will be stored in `input`. My idea is to loop through the `input` string and match it with `alphabet`, and hence find out its pair in `key` string. This is easy, since the pairs will have the same index. However, how do I swap them? I can use a loop in `swap(input[i], key[i])` but that will just make every string as `ZYXW...` I am not able to write the logic here... Below is my code till now in entirety.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

   int main()
{

       string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
       string key {"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"};
       int choice {};

       cout<<"Welcome to the Cypher Program";
       cout<<"\nYou can encode and decode your messages to make sure they remain secret!";
       cout<<"\nWould you like to encode(Press 1) or decode(Press 2) a message?"<<endl;

       cin>>choice;
       //Encoding
       if (choice == 1)
       {
           string input {};
           cout<<"Enter a string to encrypt"<<endl;
           getline(cin.ignore(), input);  //testString

           cout<<"Your encrypted message is: "<<endl;
           for(int i {0}; i<input.length(); i++){
               swap(input[i], key[i]);
           }
           cout<<input;                  //ZYXWVUTSRQ
       }


       return 0;

}
```

What I really want to do is:

- Get input from user
- For each letter in input, find out its index in `alphabet`
- Using this index, swap the character with `key`.
- Display the new string back to user.

Comment: You’re missing the “find the index” part here. Add that. And don’t swap, replace. You don’t want to change they key.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Oh ok, I will use replace instead of swap. But how do I find the index? I am not able to think of any sort of logic yet :-/

Comment: Since you want to find the character in a string then `std::string`’s `find()` method will be useful

Comment: Why do you need swapping? The `key` should be constant and it shall not be changed while encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to discuss two simple approaches here.

1. First is to just do what you've suggested in the first place, find the index of the letter from `alhphabet` and use that index to find encoded letter from `key`.
2. You can use a simple trick here by observing the pattern in your encoding. Whenever it's an uppercase letter, you can just subtract `'A'` from its ASCII value to get `offset` and subtract that offset from ASCII value of `z` to get encoded letter. You can notice similar pattern when it's a lowercase letter.

Below is the sample code for both approaches.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    string key {"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"};
    string input1 {"testString"}, input2 {"testString"};
    cout<<"Your encrypted message is (Approach 1) : "<<endl;
    // Approach 1
    for(int i {0}; i<input1.length(); i++){
        int idx;
        for(idx=0;idx<alphabet.length();idx++) // find index from alphabet
            if(input1[i]==alphabet[idx])
                break;
        input1[i] = key[idx]; // replace with key
    }
    cout<<input1<<endl; //GVHGhGIRMT
    // Approach 2
    cout<<"Your encrypted message is (Approach 2) : "<<endl;
    for(int i {0}; i<input2.length(); i++){
        if(input2[i] >= 'A' && input2[i]<='Z')
            input2[i] = 'z' - (input2[i]-'A');
        else if(input2[i] >= 'a' && input2[i]<='z')
            input2[i] = 'A' + ('z'-input2[i]);
    }
    cout<<input2; //GVHGhGIRMT
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Your encrypted message is (Approach 1) : 
GVHGhGIRMT
Your encrypted message is (Approach 2) : 
GVHGhGIRMT
```

Comment: Thank you, but will the approach 2 be still valid if I try to incorporate other characters such as whitespace and underscores?

Comment: It depends on what your encoded key is, for those characters. If `alphabet-key` have a relation/pattern among them, like in case lowercase and uppercase letters, then Approach 2 can be modified to incorporate those characters too. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Find index of character in original string

```
if (input[i] >= 97)
{
    index = input[i]-97; 

}
else
{
    index = (input[i]-65) + 26; 
}
```

now use

```
input[i] = key[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, your original code was not that bad. You just need to replace the swap with an assignment. That leaves you originla data untouched.

```
input[i] = key[alphabet.find(input[i])];
```

Youd should add `const` before "alphabet" and "key" then the compiler would have prevented your code.

By the way, with this symmetric key, encoding and decoding is the same.

Not sure why you are writing `getline(cin.ignore(), input);`  instead of `getline(cin, input);`. That should be corrected.

The calculation approach has the advantage that the key string will not be in exe file. 
You could calculate the result also with XOR 255 (`result += input[i] ^255`, which flips all bits, or with 256-input[i];

Below a "more modern" C++ solution using the `std::transform`-algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // The encoding alphabet and key
    constexpr std::string_view alphabet{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ _" };
    constexpr std::string_view  key{ "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba_ " };    

    // String to encrypt
    std::string message{"Hello world"};

    // Here we will store the result
    std::string result;

    std::transform(message.begin(), message.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&key, &alphabet](const char c)
        { size_t pos{ alphabet.find(c) }; return (pos != std::string::npos) ? key[pos] : '_'; });

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\nEncrypted: " << result << "\n";

    message = result;
    result.clear();
    std::transform(message.begin(), message.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&key, &alphabet](const char c)
        { size_t pos{ alphabet.find(c) }; return (pos != std::string::npos) ? key[pos] : '_'; });

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\nDecrypted: " << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```